Updated database for polling?
I was looking around for an updated database/list for national polling of 2024 US elections without much success.  The obvious first try is wikipedia but it is not updated regularly (for example, it is currently 4 days behind).  Are there any other lists that are updated more regularly?

Do you have any reason to suspect that the Wikipedia page is out-of-date? I notice, for example, that there were no polls concluded between May 26 and May 31. Is it not plausible that no further polls have concluded since then?

@F1Krazy, yes, I have reason to think so.  Note that the "aggregations" of the polls, listed in sections above the one I linked, are updated to 3 june 2024 (including some changes in the figures).  This indicates that there were individual polls in the meantime that were not reported in the "national poll results" section.

I'm not sure if complaining about a source edited by volunteers being 4 days behind justifies a Q here. Polling results often don't change that fast anyway.

@againstverylongusernames It seems like a reasonable question, not a complaint.

The best database of political polls I know of is the FiveThirtyEight polling tracker.  They're adding polls every day, and they make it available both via their website and for download.
That said, the Morning Consult poll that's currently at the top of the Wikipedia list appears to be the most recent national, presidental poll - 538 doesn't have anything newer in that combination. It also was polling from May 31st to June 2nd (which isn't clear from Wikipedia's entry), and 538 added it on the 2nd.

Here are the two most useful polling aggregators that I like to follow.

https://elections2024.thehill.com/national/harris-trump-general/
https://www.realclearpolling.com/polls/president/general/2024/trump-vs-harris

In particular, The Hill's agregator is interesting because the polling in 2016 and 2020 was famously off by a few percentage points and this one has a toggle that allows you to adjust the polling if you believe the 2024 election will have a similar polling bias.

National polling is kinda irrelevant. What really matters for pres. election purposes are the battleground states.

@againstverylongusernames Depends on what you're using the poll for. If you just want to predict who would win if the election were held today, you're right. But if you care about national sentiments.

@againstverylongusernames The RCP page has links to Battleground State polling in: Arizona | Nevada | Wisconsin | Michigan | Pennsylvania | North Carolina | Georgia on it.
